# PostgreSQL reset id for every new year or increment for same year

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like

```
id  name  xxx yyy receipt_id receipt_year
1   abcd  x   a   1          2018
2   abc   y   b   2          2018
3   abd   z   c   3          2018
4   abe   z   d   4          2018
```

id column is bigserial (big int with auto increment) and i am increasing receipt_id manually. I want to reset receipt_id every year i.e start with 1 for every new year. How can i do this in a better way ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a trigger that creates a sequence per year on demand:

```
CREATE TABLE receipt(
   id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
   receipt_id integer NOT NULL,
   receipt_year smallint NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION id_for_year() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   seqname text := 'seq_' || NEW.receipt_year;
BEGIN
   IF seqname IS NOT NULL THEN
      EXECUTE 'CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS ' || seqname;
      EXECUTE 'SELECT nextval($1)' INTO NEW.receipt_id USING seqname::regclass;
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER id_for_year BEFORE INSERT ON receipt FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE id_for_year();

INSERT INTO receipt(receipt_year) VALUES (2018);
INSERT INTO receipt(receipt_year) VALUES (2017);
INSERT INTO receipt(receipt_year) VALUES (2017);
NOTICE:  relation "seq_2017" already exists, skipping

TABLE receipt;
 id | receipt_id | receipt_year 
----+------------+--------------
  1 |          1 |         2018
  2 |          1 |         2017
  3 |          2 |         2017
(3 rows)
```

Comment: It is giving error: **syntax error at or near "NOT" LINE 1: CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS seq_2018 ^ QUERY: CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS seq_2018 CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function hp_periphery.id_for_year() line 5 at EXECUTE statement**

Comment: You are using an old PostgreSQL version. Instead of using `IF NOT EXISTS`, you will have to explicitly test for existence of the sequence, e.g. using `information_schema.sequences`.